# Github organization name change does not change URL route string

Tags: github

I created an organization named "dot-quiver" on version control software Github. Since I dislike its name, I changed on settings. I expect it to change also on the URL. As you can see, the previous name remains.

[image: organization_name]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears you have changed the `Organization display name`. That will ONLY change the display name of the org.

To change the real name of the org go to `https://github.com/organizations/<org name>/settings/profile`. Then scroll all the way down into the `Danger zone` then click the `Rename organization` option. You will get a message about what will happen then you click `I understand, let’s rename my organization`. A pop-up will appear with the current name of the org where you can change it. When you are done you click `Change organization’s name` and the org name should be changed. Note it may take a few minutes for the change to take effect.

Comment: you will not see danger zone if you were not the one who created organization

Comment: @MykolaRiabchenko Did not know that

Comment: That's not true; any owner can rename the organisation, regardless of who created it.